# can we save a partially trained Machine Learning model, reload it again and train from the point it was saved?

Tags: machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want to know is there any way in which we can partially save a Scikit-Learn Machine Learning model and reload it again to train it from the point it was saved before?

Comment: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_persistence.html

Answer (score 1):

For models such as Scikitlearn applied to sentiment analysis, I would suspect you need to save two important things: 1) your model, 2) your vectorizer.
Remember that after training your model, your words are represented by a vector of length N, and that is defined according to your total number of words.
Below is a piece from my test-model and test-vectorizer saved in order to be used latter.

**SAVING THE MODEL**

```
import pickle 
pickle.dump(vectorizer, open("model5vectorizer.pickle", "wb"))
pickle.dump(classifier_fitted, open("model5.pickle", "wb"))
```

**LOADING THE MODEL IN A NEW SCRIPT (.py)**

```
import pickle
model = pickle.load(open("model5.pickle", "rb"))
vectorizer = pickle.load(open("model5vectorizer.pickle", "rb"))
```

**TEST YOUR MODEL**

```
sentence_test = ["Results by Andutta et al (2013), were completely wrong and unrealistic."]
```

**USING THE VECTORIZER (model5vectorizer.pickle) !!**

```
sentence_test_data = vectorizer.transform(sentence_test) 
print("### sentence_test ###")
print(sentence_test)
print("### sentence_test_data ###")
print(sentence_test_data)
# OBS-1: VECTOR HERE WILL HAVE SAME LENGTH AS BEFORE :)
# OBS-2: If you load the default vectorizer or a different one, then you may see the following problems
# sklearn.exceptions.NotFittedError: TfidfVectorizer - Vocabulary wasn't fitted.
# # ValueError: X has 8 features per sample; expecting 11
result1 = model.predict(sentence_test_data) # using saved vectorizer from calibrated model
print("### RESULT ###")
print(result1)
```

Hope that helps.

Regards,

Andutta

Answer (score 0):

When a data set is fitted to a Scikit-learn machine learning model, it is trained and supposedly ready to be used for prediction purposes. By training a model with let's say, 100 samples and using it and then going back to it and fitting another 50 samples to it, you will not make it better but you will rebuild it. 
If your purpose is to build a model and make it more powerful as it interacts with more samples, you would be thinking of a real-time condition, such as a mobile robot for mapping an environment with a Kalman Filter.

Comment: Google Colab provides computation time of around 12 hours but my model is taking more than this time to train how to overcome the problem?